# Sort a matrix defined as a vector<double>

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, qsort

Assume I have a square matrix `A` of size `n`, defined as a `std::vector<double>`.

```
std::vector<double> A(n*n);
```

The elements of the matrix are accessed the usual way:

```
double a_ij = A[i*n + j];
```

I need to sort the rows of the matrix in ascending order with respect to the first column.

The qsort function allows me to do it with arrays and function pointers, but I would like to find a way to accomplish this with vectors and `std::sort`.

Also, note that I do not wish to define my matrix as a vector of vectors for performance reasons.

**Edit:**

The function I passed to qsort:

```
static int comparisonFunction(const void* firstRow, const void* secondRow) 
{
    if (((double *)firstRow)[0] < ((double *)secondRow)[0]) return -1;
    else if (((double *)secondRow)[0] < ((double *)firstRow)[0]) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

And the call:

```
std::qsort(matrixArray, nbRows, sizeof(double)*nbRows, comparisonFunction);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate about the "performance reasons"?

Comment: I need to perform heavy computations on the sorted matrix, so memory contiguity is preferable.

Comment: you need a wrapper around it to allow `begin` and `end` to iterate over rows

Comment: Why not make an explicit `Matrix` class to wrap the vector, with iterators and possibly nicer element access functions?

Comment: the best way would be to create a class `Matrix` that internally stores a `vector<double>` and have matrix-like access and `begin` `end` over rows, columns and underlying contiguous data if needed. More work, but the most elegant solution if you invest in it.

Comment: If you got `qsort` to work, then you must be close. `std::sort` takes the `begin` and `end` of what you want to iterate over, and then some form of functor, or even a lambda. What did you feed into qsort?

Comment: @doctorlove : I added some precision about how I got qsort to work.

Comment: I would probably do it in two steps. Sort a vector of pairs containing first entry of each row and the original index, then use the result of this to rearrange the matrix. Sorting a vector is fast and you save moving the full rows during the sorting.

Answer (score 3):

`std::sort` works on iterators, and doesn't care about the iterator implementation. Hence, if you define a `struct RowIter` which wraps a `std::vector<double>& matrix`, with a member `size_t RowSize` for `operator+(size_t)` (and `operator-`, `operator++` etc) and a `Row operator*() const`, then `std::sort` can sort by that iterator.

Still quite a bit more work than `qsort`, unfortunately, but it would generalize to non-POD types.

Comment: Should RowIter inherit from RandomAccessIterator ?

Comment: @Dooggy: Not inherit, but it should indeed implement the whole RandomAccessIterator concept. Fixed.

Comment: @Dooggy: since you're new and might be confusing StackOverflow for a forum, we're trying to keep this a Q&A website. It is very much appreciated when you contribute your final solution, but you can just put that as an answer. (There's intentionally no rule against answering your own questions)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to replace `qsort` with `std::sort` to sort the underlying array, but you have to define:

- a Row type that directly accesses the underlying storage of the vector - you cannot use a vector here because even if an array or arrays is still an array, a vector of vectors is not a vector of square size. Worse, I know no portable way to assign an existing storage to a vector. That Row type will have to be move-constructible and move-assignable, and correctly support swap.
- a RandomAccessIterator on that Row type, able to correctly process the end of the underlying array.

It is up to you to do that, but all the versions of standard C++ explicitly support the C library, so there is no harm is using `qsort` in this use case because it is much simpler and in the end less error-prone. The `qsort` way only required 7 lines, which is easy to control and peer review. The *nice* C++ way will require at least 2 classes with non-trivial constructors so much more lines and much more possibilities of mistakes in them.

If you really cannot use `qsort`, maybe for internal coding rules, then I would simply copy the data to a vector of vectors, sort it and copy the data back to the initial vector. It involves 2 additional full copies of the matrix but at least use standard classes and requires far less coding.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to keep the `qsort()` and just use `std::vector::data()`, which returns a pointer to the first element, thus allowing you to use a `std::vector` much the same as a C array:

```
std::qsort(matrixArray.data(), nbRows, sizeof(double)*nbRows, comparisonFunction);
```

Using `std::sort()` properly is possible, but verbose, as you would not only need an random access iterator class to iterate by rows, but also a class that abstracts a row so that `std::sort()` can swap them.

A way around that, but still using `std::sort` is to extract the elements you want to sort into their own `std::vector` along with an index. Then sort that vector and finally reorder the rows in the original matrix by the indices in that vector.

```
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <algorithm>

const int n = 10;

std::vector<double>
row_sort(std::vector<double> const& A)
{
  std::vector<std::tuple<int, double> > first_element(n);
  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
    first_element[i] = std::make_tuple(i, A[i*n]);
  }

  std::sort(std::begin(first_element), std::end(first_element),
            [](std::tuple<int, double> const& lhs,
               std::tuple<int, double> const& rhs)
            {
              return std::get<1>(lhs) < std::get<1>(rhs);
            });

  std::vector<double> result(n*n);
  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
    std::copy_n(&A[std::get<0>(first_element[i])*n], n, &result[i*n]);
  }

  return result;
}
```